# Why is there no interface to get user/group information in std filesystem library extension in C++1y?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, boost-filesystem

[`stat()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_%28system_call%29) system call has been provided by POSIX compliance operating system to fetch various information about a particular file. Microsoft also provides [`_stat()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff.aspx) system calls similar to `stat()`.

Well most of the useful interfaces is provided in library extension **"filesystem"** proposed([N3803](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/10/n3803)) in C++1y except one important (i.e. group and user id of owner of file).

I am sure that this must have been thought by boost community in their original design. I wanted to know what else could be design constraints which might have restricted it to be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all systems have a concept of users and groups. Unix has, Windows has something along the same lines. But C++ is a language to program *anything*, even your toaster. Until the brave NetBSD folks port their system to it, chances are there won't even be distinct users.

Comment: Your toaster wouldn't qualify as a hosted platform, and not be required by the `C++` standard to provide `filesystem` at all.

Comment: While there may be some truth to this answer, it also seems that it should be possible to simply return the same group/user ID, maybe a sentinel value even, for every file on a platform that doesn't support them. Without citing references this answer just amounts to idle speculation.